# How to interpret Chi-squared test results for these datasets?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, histogram

I have two discrete distributions (histograms) *A_i* and *B_i* and antoher one *C_i*, and I'd like to compare first two with the third one in R using chisq.test.

This is a combination of histogram A with C.
[image: This is a combination of data A with C]

And this is a combination of histogram B with C.
[image]

It is obvious that A is similar to C, but B is not.

However, when I compare this distributions in R using chisq.test, the test is not work.

```
> chisq.test(rbind(benf, benf_similar))

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  rbind(benf, benf_similar)
X-squared = 0.066483, df = 89, p-value = 1
```

---

```
> hisq.test(rbind(B, C))

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  rbind(false_data, benf)
X-squared = 20.109, df = 89, p-value = 1
```

Why chi-squared test is not correctly working in R?

---

The data used:

```
A = c(3.96142312766197, 3.5786571978524, 3.36974400407981, 3.15034401232892, 
2.93582888272906, 2.72769753293732, 2.6117089244369, 2.40429734803119, 
2.28127991491022, 2.2581906934435, 2.05358356790371, 1.97755449211918, 
1.95679629992611, 1.87271546633939, 1.79697414886439, 1.70814836693519, 
1.65714057272124, 1.54401965046302, 1.50344469996219, 1.46269940363974, 
1.41233367881787, 1.4148176966578, 1.35747577361725, 1.34781239423126, 
1.27923484620663, 1.19605998981271, 1.17841466612969, 1.17898327303528, 
1.18326135052915, 1.16606387837225, 1.04239779590061, 1.06235057090194, 
1.04513855623982, 0.98615869145205, 0.96948942028849, 0.965111912024903, 
0.970039782135154, 0.886037695643092, 0.919908061421189, 0.78934052130315, 
0.828892484615876, 0.818893878178447, 0.876261226444365, 0.845906787665646, 
0.853914519474858, 0.793848296078164, 0.763211982855336, 0.771329022496128, 
0.714441988152818, 0.682361137017442, 0.751350649553372, 0.695846285684962, 
0.692731324211259, 0.735305503080027, 0.648370397451736, 0.677399146702439, 
0.621798894408419, 0.646346147244654, 0.600559050788956, 0.502535402697678, 
0.642728434524579, 0.588593188147059, 0.578348972476024, 0.584317209837343, 
0.612007286053255, 0.568195951452063, 0.595289132444029, 0.563244288257243, 
0.609009479549682, 0.519299328969541, 0.562860299948798, 0.501484421027751, 
0.533702094468268, 0.500242095527774, 0.563523996094348, 0.535796249264213, 
0.496085824963967, 0.508808425920357, 0.519233112990755, 0.468191251198043, 
0.47569491590563, 0.437862532388957, 0.502463893702408, 0.516320779493418, 
0.484523468818522, 0.485182304334363, 0.448051205183448, 0.456611413051599, 
0.433369783496901, 0.435309047052346)
```

...

```
B = c(3.5651869975533, 3.18070604683677, 5.45263893743446, 3.77490387976232, 
3.28556448794128, 4.05452638937434, 3.11080041943376, 4.15938483047885, 
2.90108353722475, 2.83117790982174, 2.13212163579168, 1.81754631247815, 
2.3068857042992, 2.48164977280671, 1.74764068507515, 2.06221600838868, 
1.46801817546312, 1.57287661656763, 1.1883956658511, 1.1883956658511, 
1.43306536176162, 1.57287661656763, 0.978678783642083, 1.25830129325411, 
0.873820342537574, 0.838867528836071, 0.838867528836071, 0.978678783642083, 
0.873820342537574, 0.594197832925551, 1.01363159734359, 1.08353722474659, 
0.873820342537574, 0.873820342537574, 0.629150646627053, 0.94372596994058, 
0.699056274030059, 1.1534428521496, 0.873820342537574, 0.908773156239077, 
0.664103460328556, 0.454386578119539, 0.524292205522545, 0.314575323313527, 
0.524292205522545, 0.384480950716533, 0.664103460328556, 0.384480950716533, 
0.34952813701503, 0.174764068507515, 0.314575323313527, 0.244669695910521, 
0.279622509612024, 0.244669695910521, 4.19433764418036, 0.244669695910521, 
0.174764068507515, 0.209716882209018, 0.104858441104509, 4.47396015379238, 
0.209716882209018, 0.279622509612024, 0.174764068507515, 0.174764068507515, 
0.244669695910521, 1.11849003844809, 0.174764068507515, 0.0699056274030059, 
0.174764068507515, 0.629150646627053, 0.139811254806012, 0.139811254806012, 
0.174764068507515, 3.42537574274729, 0.139811254806012, 0.139811254806012, 
0.279622509612024, 0.034952813701503, 0.139811254806012, 0.104858441104509, 
2.13212163579168, 0.279622509612024, 0.174764068507515, 0.174764068507515, 
0.034952813701503, 0.104858441104509, 0.139811254806012, 0.0699056274030059, 
0.419433764418036, 0)
```

...

```
C = c(3.92433638501126, 3.61003952523951, 3.34237454461746, 3.11167625717403, 
2.91077874523436, 2.73425634041095, 2.57792544954639, 2.43850828487275, 
2.31340025220091, 2.20050553278331, 2.09811861739714, 2.00483747378685, 
1.91949891122441, 1.8411297918393, 1.76890973340022, 1.70214226471783, 
1.64023227989963, 1.58266824291089, 1.52900801426315, 1.47886746784472, 
1.43191127738965, 1.38784540494608, 1.34641093546487, 1.30737898421165, 
1.27054646533473, 1.23573255634394, 1.2027757285288, 1.17153124036677, 
1.14186901183415, 1.11367181375524, 1.08683371902807, 1.06125877257687, 
1.03685984482026, 1.01355763977689, 0.991279834009955, 0.969960326707686, 
0.949538584516721, 0.929959067448574, 0.911170724390719, 0.893126548571656, 
0.875783184828555, 0.859100581768677, 0.843041682949149, 0.827572152062404, 
0.812660127837227, 0.79827600497311, 0.784392237937772, 0.770983164891721, 
0.758024849371419, 0.745494937675839, 0.733372530168874, 0.721638064938594, 
0.710273212451053, 0.699260780005144, 0.688584624940932, 0.678229575679936, 
0.668181359784938, 0.658426538321979, 0.648952445889676, 0.639747135752979, 
0.630799329581751, 0.622098371349274, 0.613634184994671, 0.605397235495354, 
0.597378493033454, 0.589569399972962, 0.581961840393794, 0.574548111954624, 
0.567320899879528, 0.560273252883676, 0.553398560871566, 0.546690534257256, 
0.54014318477081, 0.533750807627639, 0.52750796494923, 0.521409470334011, 
0.515450374486255, 0.509625951819395, 0.503931687957506, 0.498363268065479, 
0.492916565944476, 0.487587633834759, 0.482372692872924, 0.477268124155108, 
0.472270460361622, 0.467376377902461, 0.462582689546118, 0.457886337497497, 
0.45328438689322, 0.448774019685283)
```

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Yes, I've shared them.

Comment: Hint: What is the null hypothesis of the test?

Comment: Why do you want to compare these using `chisq.test`? What do these data represent? There is almost surely nothing wrong with R's implementation of that test, it's among the most commonly used statistical software packages & has been around for *decades*. The code is open-source, you can check the calculations for yourself. The leap from 'this test does not tell me what I want' to 'the test is wrong' is really quite baffling statistical practice.

Comment: Could you please describe what your data corresponds to. I don't think a chi-squared is the correct test to compare these distributions. Additionnaly, histograms are usually used for continuous data, while barplots are usually used for categorical data.

Comment: I'd like to use Benford law to test distirbutions of the first two digits of my numeric data. The data for Benford distribution is stored in C. The data A looks very similar to Benford distribution, but chi-square doesn't show this.

Comment: It should be `cbind` to compare the *column* vectors, R's behavior.

Comment: ~I did not choose a statistical procedure carefully. It appears that I do not understand its mechanism/appropriate application -- nor the interpretation. An unrelated result I obtain is not what I am after. Conclusion: the code implementation is wrong.  The answer to your question *Why chi-squared test is not correctly working in R?* does not come to live since the test is correctly implemented.

Comment: Your problem is one due to the miss scaling of chi-squared. With 93 degrees of freedom a chi-squared value of 20 is not at all significant. See for example this [chi-squared calculator](https://www.statology.org/chi-square-p-value-calculator/)webpage which can compute the significance thresholds. R is working correctly the problem is that you haven't told it anything about your confidence in the measurements so it has defaulted to sigma=1.

Comment: And how should I scale chi-sqaure? Could you recommend something to read?